# how to resize image on outlook email by css or c#

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

```
<html><head><style>table{width:100%;}  table tr{padding-top:10px;} table tr td {border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; padding-top:10px; padding-left:8px;} table tr.masthead td {border-bottom:0;} table h3.title{margin:20px 0 20px 0;} .clearfix{clear:both;} .title{color:#808080;}  .masthead{background-color:#0070C0;color:#fff;} .masthead td{border-color:#0070C0; padding:0; margin:0;} </style></head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr class="masthead" border="0"><th style="padding:15px 5px 15px 8px; text-align:left; border:1px solid #0070C0;"><h3>Test Summary</h3></th><th align="right" style="padding:15px 5px 15px 5px; border:1px solid #0070C0;"><img height="40px" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" src="http://docs.testplant.com/sites/default/files/TestPlant%20logo%20-%202col.png"></th></tr><tr><td class="title">Name</td> 
</tr>
 </table></body></html>
```

Sending email on c# where generate html to resize image to be smaller than its actual size, I debugged into it and found out it work on the html page, however it did not work on microsoft outlook when sent to it.
Any idea?

Comment: this is whole html

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? Hard to infer from the way it is now.

Comment: I stripped out the tbody part, yes that is whole html

Comment: I sent the above html in c# code through SMTP, when rendered on the email, the image is not resize, even though I specified on the style to make image smaller, however it rendered correctly on the html page, but not in the outlook email

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using MailMessage class in System.Net.Mail namespace. You can append a HTML string to the body of the email.

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.Body = bodyMessage.ToString();

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
//other client settings
client.Send(msg);
```